# Is there a way to invoke C# methods in an oracle trigger or stored procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle

As captioned, is there a way to invoke .NET(core) methods in an Oracle trigger/stored procedure?

Comment: No. Why are you asking in the first place? What does that method do? You may be able to create a PL/SQL or Java package, or the very idea may be wrong.

Comment: While you can create external procedures that make OS calls on the database host, which can be written to call just about anything if you have enough piping to accomplish it, that's probably not a path you want to go down. Same thing for using UTL_TCP to establish a connection with a remote daemon which could initiate just about any remote action you can program. Possible, but rather complicated and messy. Or httpuritype/utl_http to call a REST service of some kind. Possible, not optimal. Instead turn it around, and make your .NET program initiate actions in Oracle rather than vice-versa.

Comment: the whole idea is once the record value was changed, a proper method in C# program can be invoked, I can query the table every 3 seconds to scan the value change but it's not efficiently.